# Avoid acronym list when acronym environment is \include[d]

Tags: acronyms, include

I want to keep my `acronym` environment in a separate file and avoid printing out the whole acronym list. Still the option `[nolist]` of the `acronym` package seems not to work when the acronym environment is included into the main document.

Please consider the following MWE

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[nolist]{acronym}
\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{acronym.tex}

\begin{acronym}
  \acro{NLP}{Natural Language Processing}
\end{acronym}

\end{filecontents}


\begin{document}

First use of \ac{NLP}. Second use of \ac{NLP}.

\include{acronym}

\end{document}
```

which gives

[image]

Yet when I take the option `[nolist]` out I get the correct

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I get the expected result if I use `\input` instead of `\include`.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[nolist]{acronym}
\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{acronym.tex}

\begin{acronym}
  \acro{NLP}{Natural Language Processing}
\end{acronym}

\end{filecontents}


\begin{document}

First use of \ac{NLP}. Second use of \ac{NLP}.

\input{acronym}

\end{document}
```

[image]